# How to change MAC address on Mac OS X 10.7.3 Lion?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, osx-lion, mac-address

I'm trying to change the MAC address for the interface en1.

```
ifconfig
```

Output:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 48:4b:29:36:4f:79 
    inet6 fe80::4a5b:39ff:fe46:5f89%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 1c:3b:d6:d6:3a:25 
    inet6 fe80::1e4b:d6ff:fed6:4a26%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
    inet 192.168.1.105 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Entered commands:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/bin/airport
sudo airport -z
sudo ifconfig en1 ether B2:E6:1C:0B:C7:C9
sudo ifconfig en1 lladdr B2:E6:1C:0B:C7:C9
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig en1 up
ifcongig
```

Output:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 48:4b:29:36:4f:79 
    inet6 fe80::4a5b:39ff:fe46:5f89%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether b2:e6:1c:0b:c7:c9 
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
```

It can be seen that the address has changed. But if you go to "System Preferences / Network / Wi-Fi / Advanced / Hardware" there appears an old MAC address 1c:3b:d6:d6:3a:25. And also enabled on the router Wireless MAC Filter is not allow to go network with the old address. Which means that the address is not changed. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo airport --disassociate
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig en1 ether B2:E6:1C:0B:C7:C9
sudo ifconfig en1 up
```

Comment: The above commands do not work on High Sierra, it gives the following error: `ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Invalid argument`